# DB Port not considered while booting up Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I have been given a Spring boot application to dockerize.

**Overview**

- Application is a Springboot application.
- Built using Gradle.
- Application Properties using application.yml.
- Database : DBServer:1435 ( Port is not default 1433).

Initially I created the docker image and got the application up.
Later the DB port was changed to 1435. Now I have updated the JDBC url in datasource section of profiles in application.yml located in src\main\resources.
DB_IP and DB_NAME are passed when booting up docker image.

```
spring:
  profiles: dev,staging,prod
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://${DB_IP}:1435;databaseName=${DB_NAME}"
    username: "${DB_USER}"
    password: "${DB_PASS}"
    initialize: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Now application won't boot and instead defaulting to port 1433. Error is as below. I am not sure why it is defaulting to 1433. Any idea?

**I tried connecting to DB instance from the docker machine and it works fine.

 Further I checked using Telnet and port 1435 can be connected.**

```
2018-02-07 16:54:18,118 ERROR main  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.17.193.240, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:257)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2385)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:567)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1955)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:51)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at au.com.outware.swepad.Application.main(Application.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
2018-02-07 16:54:18,129 WARN main  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.17.193.240, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Comment: check `org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection` to make sure it is not hard-coded or something

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry if it sounds basic, I am new to this and how do we check org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection ?
There is no file with that name in source code directory.

Comment: Sorry I was assuming that this was your code.  Check / Post the code for au.com.outware.swepad.Application.main(Application.java:49).  Also try `grep`ing your entire code for `1433` - maybe some xml file?

Comment: the line 49 has this `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); `  And I tried searching for 1433. The only place I found is in application.yml. Is there any port configuration done in Flyway config

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that trips up many Java apps trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. Following steps will solve your issue.

1. Open **SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager**.
2. Click **Protocol** for **SQLEXPRESS** under **SQL Server Network Configuration** on the left pane. On the right pane, right- click **TCP/IP**, and select **Properties**.
3. On the **TCP/IP** Properties dialog box that appears, click the **IP Addresses** tab.
4. Scroll down to locate the **IPALL** node. Remove any value, if present for **TCP Dynamic Ports** and specify **1433** for **TCP Port**.
5. Click **OK**.
6. Again right-click **TCP/IP** on the right pane, and select **Enable**.
7. On the **SQL Server Services** node, right-click **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**, and select **Restart**.

[image]

Your connection string in application.properties must look like following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=YourDBName
```